# Index for array that matches vectorwise

Tags: r

I have an array

```
h <- array(0, c(100, 5, 9));
```

The length 9 vector is sort of an identification sequence. Given some i in 1:100, is there a way I can obtain the index j in 1:5 for which the length 9 sequence matches some vector V? ie. the index j such that

```
identical(h(i,j,1:9),V)
```

is true.

Edit: this is assuming that one of the 5 do match for the given i. It'd be even better if one can obtain the pair (i,j) for which it matches with V.

Comment: `sapply(1:5, function(ind) identical(h[71, ind, 1:9], V))`

Comment: It worked! Thanks.